# What characters are allowed in a dynamic segment (param) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes

I am using Rails and have a user entered field that can become a param in the URL. I'd like to add a validation that stops the users from entering any fields that will cause routing errors, as currently if the user enters a value like that we get an error "No route matches [GET]..." So far I know periods and slashes are not allowed...

What regex should I use for my validation? Or what regex does Rails use by default for dynamic segments?

Comment: Why not just define the route with your own `:constraints`?

Comment: In my case it is the resources route, but I am using strings for :id. I have no particular desire to change the constraints, I just want to know what they are so I can enforce them before it is a problem, rather than keep adding each example I find of a character that breaks it.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you define it then you can use the same regex to validate input, eliminating ever having to think about it regardless of anything on the Rails side (which could change across versions, etc.)

Comment: I suppose I can add ":id => %r/.+/", but I don't know what previously forbidden characters I am allowing and in the process breaking other things. For example, changing it to that breaks adding .json to the end to get the response formatted in JSON. I don't want to break built-in Rails functionality, I just want to know what to disallow so I don't break it.

Comment: ... I'm saying be relatively restrictive, not put in a `.`, because that would be kind of silly. Without knowing the type of things you want to allow, it's difficult to understand what's difficult about providing a relatively restrictive regex (like chars, underscore, numbers, and maybe a few other things).

Comment: I don't want to be any more restrictive than necessary - in this particular case the values are values from multiple outside systems, which I do not know what they allow. So I'd like to be as nonrestrictive as possible without breaking built-in Rails functionality. I'm still pretty new to Rails, so I don't know what all the built-in functionality is. When I tried to read the docs and source, I found a list of separators %w( / . ? ) that are clearly not allowed, but I never found where it actually matches it to see if anything else is restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has actually answered the question, just suggested workarounds. (Which are probably better, if you are in the right circumstances to use them.) I experimented to find the characters that caused issues. I tested all punctuation available on a standard US keyboard. I also tested space and (horizontal) tab. I did not test any extended Unicode punctuation, nor control characters.

The characters I found to cause problems in Rails 3.2.9, using webrick and the composite_primary_keys gem are:

```
,/.%
```

To validate that a field contains none of these characters:

```
validates :field_name, :format => { :with => /\A[^,\/\.%]*\z/, 
  :message => "commas, slashes, periods, and percent signs (,/.%) are not allowed"}
```

Many of the other characters I tried are not valid directly in URLs, but Rails automatically URL encodes them so they do not cause an issue.

As mentioned in the comments on the original question, some of these characters can be enabled by configuring Rails other than the defaults, but in doing so you will disable other features of Rails. To enable them you need to add `:constraints` or `:id` settings in your route definition.

I have not completely tested enabling all these characters, but I believe the consequences are:

```
Ch  Consequence of enabling use
--  ---------------------------------------
,   Must not use gem composite_primary_keys
/   Limits ability to route to child items
.   Disables automatic format handling
%   Not sure this can be enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can let the user insert whatever, than use to_params + parameterize to write the url, and if you want some regex, take a look at the parameterize source code.

Example of to_params, the documentation and source code see:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't help. Parameterize just throws away everything but alphanumeric, dash, and underscore. I can't throw away characters, as I still need to be able to match on them.

Comment: I didn't get it so... The to_param method on your class won't modify any char the user enters, it will just define how the url is written (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param). If your intent is just a custom "pretty url", friendlyid gem might help:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Comment: My point is that a custom "pretty url" is not my intent at all. This table, defined outside Rails, uses string IDs, not numeric. If I allow the user to insert whatever, but then throw it away in the URL, my URL no longer uniquely matches a record.

Comment: Well, in that case you can validate uniqueness with http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

From rails code in action_pack action_dispath/journey/path/pattern.rb

```
@separator_re = "([^#{separator}]+)" # where separator comes from @separators = "/.?"
```

So the default regular expression used to match a dynamic segment seems to be:

```
/([^\/\.\?])/
```